# User activity feed - favorited, badges, etc

Tags: feature-request, feed

I was just thinking it would be useful if there was a stream generated from activity such as adding a post to favorites.  Also an aggregate of lots of different recent activity, for example earning a badge, selecting an answer, leaving a comment, etc..  this could be used for a personal website or social network then as a badge of activity.

Most of all the feed of the favorites would be great for me as more and more I find some things at SO such a great reference that I bookmark that thread, it would be sweet if I could have these import and use the feed in various ways.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but I believe you can use the API to do this. http://stackapps.com

Comment: Yup, you can use [Stack2RSS](http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s) for this very purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the recent activity of any user on [their profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82330/zac?tab=activity). This can also be converted to an RSS feed with [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s) (as George Edison said in the comments):

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/82330/timeline

You can also get a stream of their favourites as an RSS feed:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/82330/favorites

Comment: That area of the profile does not include favorited posts as part of the activity stream does it?  That in particular is what my question is about.  Thanks to you and George for showing me Stack2RSS

Comment: The RSS feeds are not working :(

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be supported directly now, now need to convert.  Just add the user id to the end of the url, like so: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/258662